# Statistical Test Accounting for Multiple Limbs Per Subject (correlated, non-independent data)

Tags: anova, mixed-model, t-test, repeated-measures, independence

I'm analyzing a small dataset (n~100) where patients are counted twice at the same point in time - once for a right limb, and once for a left limb. In other words, the sample is correlated.

I want to compare a mean measurement for males vs. females. I would like to use my full sample, rather than two -two-sample t-tests, in order to maintain power.

Usually I would do repeat measures ANOVA, but we only have 2 categories, not 3.

Would I do a mixed linear effects model, or is that incorrect?

Thank you!

Comment: A mixed effects model certainly sounds like the obvious approach (lots of examples with e.g. left and right eye in ophthamology), but i  may be missing something, because i do not understand the 2 vs. 3 category comment.

Comment: Hi Bjorn, thank you for your response! I meant three or more groups